# Iterating object from getStaticProps and displaying in component template

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am trying to display the results for a database fetch that occured withing `getStaticProps` but when I map the object in the component template I get the following errors. I would like to display all the data from the returned data.

My code:

```js
import React from "react"
import { GetStaticProps } from "next"

// pages/index.tsx
import prisma from '../lib/prisma'

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const tracks = await prisma.tracks.findMany();
  return { props: { tracks } };
};

const Tracks = ({ tracks }) => {
  console.log(tracks)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All Tracks</h1>
      {tracks.map((track ) => (
        <div>{track.ts}</div>
        ))}
   </div>
  );
}

export default Tracks;
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Sat Jun 27 2020 17:43:15 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is what the response looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div>{JSON.stringify(track)}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`track.ts` is a `Date` type and basically is an `object`. You can't just render the `Date` object inside JSX. You need to convert it to string or number, for example:

```js
const Tracks = ({ tracks }) => {
  console.log(tracks)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All Tracks</h1>
      {tracks.map((track ) => (
        <div>{String(track.ts)}</div>
        ))}
   </div>
  );
}
```